# Mapping database table with no primary key using fluent API

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am working on an application that has many already existing table mappings like so

```
public DbSet<Activity> Activities { get; set; }
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<Activity>().ToTable("Activity", "MES_WVM");
    modelBuilder.Entity<Activity>().HasKey(r => new { r.ActivityID });
}
```

Works fine for most of the tables I end up working with. I am now tasked with creating some new features, which requires me to pull data from new tables. These tables have no primary key and I do not have the access to change that. This MSDN article about [mapping with fluent api](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591617.aspx#2.1) states

> By convention, a type that has no primary key specified is treated as a complex type. There are some scenarios where Code First will not detect a complex type (for example, if you do have a property called ID, but you do not mean for it to be a primary key). In such cases, you would use the fluent API to explicitly specify that a type is a complex type.

```
modelBuilder.ComplexType<Details>();
```

Using the method above does not allow me to use `ToTable()` to map this type to a database table. How do I do this using fluent API. I would also like to emphasize that I am not about to give the tables in the DB keys, even though they reaaaaaally should.

Answer (score 0):

If the existing tables do not have a Key and you do not intend to change it, then you probably should not try to add a Key with the Fluent API.  The Fluent API will help you define the mappings between entities if they differ from conventions from the raw POCO objects, but the mappings they create should exist in the data repository.

How about you just pull data from the tables from a Linq query.  You can encapsulate this in readonly field if you like (as you say you need to pull data from new tables):

```
private string _YourData;

public string YourData 
{ 
   get { return _YourData ?? (_YourData = ExistingTable.Single(yourquery)); }
}
```

Comment: I had not intended on using Fluent API to add a key, but I still need to map my class to my database table. The application needs to know what the table and schema names are, thus the need to map.